# Config Broken After installing react-native-paper

Tags: react-native, gradle, react-native-paper

I am having problems to run a project that was running normally before

It started when I add react-native-paper/react-native-vector-icons to my project, it start giving some aapt error related to material. I was getting the following message: http://oneclickpaste.com/49188/

So I removed it. I thought that it should work fine, because before I install it the code was ok. See if everything was removed and it indeed were. 
After that something change in my react-native config(I guess). So every code that run fine is giving the same appt error or with a clean yarn install(rm -rf node_modules and rm yarn.lock and after that yarn install) is giving this new error(that for me makes no sense):

```
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':react-native-os'.
> compileSdkVersion is not specified.
```

Someone have experienced a issue similar?

My **react-native -version**:

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.60.4
```

The compileSdkVersion is cleary declared on **android/app/build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

/**
 * The react.gradle file registers a task for each build variant (e.g. bundleDebugJsAndAssets
 * and bundleReleaseJsAndAssets).
 * These basically call `react-native bundle` with the correct arguments during the Android build
 * cycle. By default, bundleDebugJsAndAssets is skipped, as in debug/dev mode we prefer to load the
 * bundle directly from the development server. Below you can see all the possible configurations
 * and their defaults. If you decide to add a configuration block, make sure to add it before the
 * `apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"` line.
 *
 * project.ext.react = [
 *   // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
 *   bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
 *
 *   // the entry file for bundle generation
 *   entryFile: "index.android.js",
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in debug mode
 *   bundleInDebug: false,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in release mode
 *   bundleInRelease: true,
 *
 *   // whether to bundle JS and assets in another build variant (if configured).
 *   // See http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Build-Variants
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'bundleIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'bundleIn${buildType}'
 *   // bundleInFreeDebug: true,
 *   // bundleInPaidRelease: true,
 *   // bundleInBeta: true,
 *
 *   // whether to disable dev mode in custom build variants (by default only disabled in release)
 *   // for example: to disable dev mode in the staging build type (if configured)
 *   devDisabledInStaging: true,
 *   // The configuration property can be in the following formats
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${productFlavor}${buildType}'
 *   //         'devDisabledIn${buildType}'
 *
 *   // the root of your project, i.e. where "package.json" lives
 *   root: "../../",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in debug mode
 *   jsBundleDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put the JS bundle asset in release mode
 *   jsBundleDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/assets/release",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in debug mode
 *   resourcesDirDebug: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/debug",
 *
 *   // where to put drawable resources / React Native assets, e.g. the ones you use via
 *   // require('./image.png')), in release mode
 *   resourcesDirRelease: "$buildDir/intermediates/res/merged/release",
 *
 *   // by default the gradle tasks are skipped if none of the JS files or assets change; this means
 *   // that we don't look at files in android/ or ios/ to determine whether the tasks are up to
 *   // date; if you have any other folders that you want to ignore for performance reasons (gradle
 *   // indexes the entire tree), add them here. Alternatively, if you have JS files in android/
 *   // for example, you might want to remove it from here.
 *   inputExcludes: ["android/**", "ios/**"],
 *
 *   // override which node gets called and with what additional arguments
 *   nodeExecutableAndArgs: ["node"],
 *
 *   // supply additional arguments to the packager
 *   extraPackagerArgs: []
 * ]
 */

project.ext.react = [
    entryFile: "index.js"
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = true

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    aaptOptions.cruncherEnabled = false
    aaptOptions.useNewCruncher = false

    lintOptions {
        disable 'MissingTranslation'
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError false
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.flipon.app"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 44
        versionName "1.2.3"
        ndk {
            abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
       signingConfigs {
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_RELEASE_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_RELEASE_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
        }
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide/apk-splits
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a":1, "x86":2]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        versionCodes.get(abi) * 1048576 + defaultConfig.versionCode
            }
        }
    }
}

buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }
  dependencies {
    // The Fabric Gradle plugin uses an open ended version to react
    // quickly to Android tooling updates
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
  }
}
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
repositories {
  maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':react-native-svg')
    compile project(':react-native-google-signin')
    compile project(':react-native-view-pdf')
    compile project(':react-native-background-timer')
    compile project(':react-native-image-picker')
    compile project(':react-native-udp')
    compile project(':react-native-tcp')
    compile project(':react-native-os')
    compile project(':react-native-randombytes')
    compile project(':react-native-maps')
    compile project(':react-native-camera')
    compile project(':react-native-firebase')
    // Firebase dependencies
    implementation project(':react-native-firebase')
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0"

    implementation (project(':react-native-maps')) {
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-base'
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-maps'
      exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services-basement'
    }

    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1"

    compile project(':react-native-orientation')
    compile project(':react-native-fetch-blob')
    compile project(':react-native-fabric')
    compile project(':react-native-linear-gradient')
    compile project(':react-native-autoheight-webview')
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
    compile project(':react-native-splash-screen')
    compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
    compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.20.1"  // From node_modules
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin.config.disableVersionCheck = true

configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
    }
}
```

UPDATE: I have update react-native and also recreate the project the issue still remains.

Comment: I have edited now. No more images.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean react-native-vector-icons? There is a long thread related to this issue [on the project site here.](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/428)

Even though you tried to remove it, your `android/app/build.gradle` file above still lists react-native-vector-icons as a dependency, so you are still pulling that in. Adding react-native-vector-icons is supposed to involve adding the reference in that file to the library's own gradle file ([per the project readme](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons#android)).

Your error is likely related to the dependency having it's own gradle file that doesn't have a proper compileSdkVersion. The thread I linked to above has a number of suggestions that have worked for folks, the [most recent of which](https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons/issues/428#issuecomment-416525219) is to add this to your android/build.gradle (with the appropriate version):

```
subprojects {
    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 27
                buildToolsVersion "27.0.2"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The problem still remains.